# How do I rearrange/reorder (not necessarily sort) a pandas dataframe index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I rearrange/reorder (not necessarily sort) a pandas dataframe index?

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'B': [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 7, 1]},
                  index=['Sat', 'Tue', 'Sun', 'Fri',
                         'Wed', 'Mon', 'Thu'])
```

which gives:

```
     A  B
Sat  1  0
Tue  2  1
Sun  3  0
Fri  4  2
Wed  5  1
Mon  6  7
Thu  7  1
```

I want to order the index by day of week (i.e., Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat). The dataframe with the rearranged/reordered index should look something like this:

```
     A  B
Sun  3  0
Mon  6  7
Tue  2  1
Wed  5  1
Thu  7  1
Fri  4  2
```

But using df.sort_index() results in an alphabetically-sorted index for df.

**How do I explicitly specify the ordering of a dataframe index?**

The solution I can think of is to pass the desired index ordering as a list during dataframe creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'])
```

**What's another way to do this without creating another dataframe?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and give it a list of indices in the order that you want them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'B': [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 7, 1]},
                  index=['Sat', 'Tue', 'Sun', 'Fri',
                         'Wed', 'Mon', 'Thu'])
df = df.loc[['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'], :]
df
#      A  B
# Sun  3  0
# Mon  6  7
# Tue  2  1
# Wed  5  1
# Thu  7  1
# Fri  4  2
# Sat  1  0
```

Comment: @ralphqq is this what you're after?

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling a bit with this myself and when you're working with MultiIndex Julien's suggestion becomes a little impractical. The solution, however, is relatively simple once you get used to it: simply reindex the dataframe with a new index. In your case this is really very easy:

```
days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']
df2 = df.reindex(days)
df2
     A  B
Sun  3  0
Mon  6  7
Tue  2  1
Wed  5  1
Thu  7  1
Fri  4  2
```

Note that you cannot perform this operation in place.

But it's probably worth noting that you might have to create the index – you certainly do for a dataframe multiple indices. So be prepared to create the index properly using `pd.Index()` or `pd.MultiIndex()`

When combined with `df.swaplevel()` this gives you great flexibility.

Comment: `reindex()` has a `level=` parameter that can be used to specify where we want to apply the re-indexing in a MultiIndex scenario

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add 'week' as register in your dataFrame in the first column.

```
# ascending
df.sort_values('week')
# reverse ascending
df.sort_values('week', ascending=False)
```

Or maybe this point could be more easy:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df.to_string())
```