# Sort pandas DataFrame rows by a list of (index) numbers

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dendrogram

I have a pandas DataFrame with 229 rows.  I have a list of index numbers (`[47, 16, 59, ...]`) and I want to re-sort the rows of my DataFrame into this order.

Details: I ran the DF through a filter (specifically, [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html), setting `get_leaves=True`). The return value includes a list of index numbers (`leaves`) in order of the dendrogram leaf nodes. I now want to sort my DF in that order, so that I can plot the clusters.

I'm sure there are many ways that I can merge a bunch of tables and drop columns but... is there a nice idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: [Pandas sorting dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), if you're simply looking to sort the dataframe, this should help.

Comment: I don't think that can work without, as answers blow suggest, adding another column... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: the answer is here [How do I rearrange/reorder (not necessarily sort) a pandas dataframe index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841373/how-do-i-rearrange-reorder-not-necessarily-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the list is the same shape as df then just paste it in like so and sort by newly created column

```
df['List']=ListOfIndices
df.sort_values(by=['List'])
```

Comment: This answer is simpler; the one above handles the case where there might be mismatches.  If I could, I'd check both. I chose this one because the shape (length) is supposed to be the same and I had a bug, so it wasn't. This code uncovered the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new column, mapping your indexes to the correct rows and then performing a sort should be the easiest way to do this.

I created some dummy data to provide an example;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df
     A   B   C   D
0    8  27   2   9
1   87  17  82  61
2   20  65  42  87
3    6  60  99  22
4    1  54  57  32

indices = [random.randrange(99) for i in range(99)]
#[54, 37, 83, 25, 44, 68, 81, 72, 61, 74, 10, 75, 24, 77, 89, 6, 59, 95, 44, 20, 72, 0, 53, 6, 61, 17, 52, 7, 95, 4, 64, 15, 46, 18, 58, 30, 3, 7, 94, 30, 93, 78, 24, 98, 65, 63, 79, 1, 43, 17, 76, 65, 85, 88, 66, 86, 10, 96, 27, 85, 66, 48, 2, 83, 25, 11, 88, 41, 88, 10, 15, 19, 75, 6, 72, 39, 28, 18, 78, 22, 71, 28, 97, 76, 47, 38, 9, 91, 69, 27, 63, 43, 19, 38, 80, 16, 35, 20, 65]
```

Code:

```
df['NewIndex'] = None # Create new column, with only None values

for indx, value in enumerate(indices):
    df['NewIndex'][value] = indx # Set index (List element number) to indx (Order in indices list)

df = df.sort_values(by=['NewIndex']) # Sort by new column
```

Output:

```
         A   B   C   D NewIndex
54  69  73  81  31        0
37  54  97  45  31        1
68  27  56  86  50        5
81  60   8  20  29        6
74  95  54  45  59        9
..  ..  ..  ..  ..      ...
84   9  67  88  38     None
87  47   9  97   2     None
90  38   6  98  50     None
92  57  51  84  37     None
99  12  88  38  90     None
```

Note, the nones and the missing rows will be due to mismatches in the indices and dataframe indexes. I did not take the time to ensure indices had 1-99 and no duplicates.

Comment: The answer below is simpler; this one handles the case where there might be mismatches.  If I could, I'd check both.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[ListOfIndices]
```

And if you want to reset the indeces:

```
df.loc[ListOfIndices].reset_index(drop=True)
```